# How to programmatically alter object created in IB

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiimageview

I've placed an image in my UIView with IB.

How do I move this image around, resize it, etc programmatically?  I cannot figure out how to reference it from my code.

Thanks a zillion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it an `IBOutlet`.

So in your `viewController`, or whatever you are loading from the `nib`, declare it like this:

```
IBOUtlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

Also, in the actual `nib`, you must connect the `File's Owner` object to the `UIImageView` in your file by right-clicking `File's owner` and dragging the correct outlet name (in this case, `myImageView`) onto the correct `UIImageView` instance in your `nib`.

Now when you load one of the objects using the `nib`, myImageView will point to the initialized `UIImageView`, or whatever else you have.

Comment: if i have multiple images, how do i specify which one i want?

Answer (score 0):

So if you create an UILabel in Inteface Builder, create an outlet like so in your .h file:

```
IBOutlet UIlabel* somelabel;
```

Then hook it up in Interface Builder and then you can access it like so:

```
somelabel.text = @"something";
```